# Kerning text in Python PIL

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library

I have some code to produce an image with text on it, using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

width = 2480
height = 3071
message = "Hello"
font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", size=900)

img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color='black')

imgDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

textWidth, textHeight = imgDraw.textsize(message, font=font)
xText = (width - textWidth) / 2
yText = (height - textHeight) / 2

imgDraw.text((152, 2100), message, font=font, fill=(255, 255, 255))

img.save('result.png')
```

I get a result like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WRob.png)

But I need the text to have less space between letters. I intend to use this code for a batch of 40+ words located in a CSV file. How can I automatically adjust the kerning? I've seen other articles pointing to a related problem but they haven't helped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I've seen other articles pointing to a related problem but they haven't helped (maybe I haven't applied them correctly)" What other "articles"? What specific code did you try writing after reading them, and how did it fail? If you couldn't figure out code to try after reading them, did you at least get a new idea? If you were confused, what confused you? Please read [ask] and try to be *specific* with both the information and the question - this is not a discussion forum. I [edit]ed the question to show good style for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As for the problem, I can think of a simple approach. Suppose you were to draw one letter at a time. Do you see how the results from `imgDraw.textsize` on each letter could be used to decide the position of the next letter?